# getting an error of incoming width constraints are unbounded in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am simple creating a horizontal scroll view with Listview.builder where i have used custom widget in itembuilder

My customwidget is also simply design...it has rounded container and inside there is a row which is divided into 2 part...first children of row containing image and second its detail..

if i use this custom widget inside listview builder its showing incoming width constraints are unbounded..error..

how to solve this...

i dont want to give it fixed width of custom widget bcz i also used in gridview too...

so its width must be dynamic...based on available width

```
 Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            children:  [
              const SizedBox(height: 100,),
              SizedBox(
                height: 100,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (_,__){
                  return const CustomWidget();
                }),
              )

          ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

custom widget

```
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  RoundedContainer(
      child: Row(
        children: [
        const Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: RoundedImage(
            // backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            imageUrl: MyImages.aymaan,

          ),
        ),
          const SizedBox(width: 10,),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
              Text('Name of the student',style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
              const Text('School name'),
            ],),
          ),

      ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `ListView` is running horizontally, the `Row` that is in the list item need to know how to limit its width.

If you can't change anything in the `CustomWidget`, you can just constraint the width in the `ListView` item builder.

```
ListView.builder(
// ...
itemBuilder: (_, __) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: 300, // for example
    child: const CustomWidget(),
  );
})
```